# select values from a db table based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I want to get organized data through a query

Table 1:

```
Name     Val     Pid
CA1      2      123
CA2      3      123
CA3      9      123
CA5      6      123
CA4      3      123
```

I want to write a query that provides me just the Val for a parent id but in a structured format,

i want to get the value like 2 3 9 3 6

if i just do

```
select val from table1 where pid='123'
```

i would get 2 3 9 6 3 which is of format CA1,CA2,CA3,CA5,CA4

**desired output:**
but i want the value in 2 3 9 3 6 which is of format **CA1,CA2,CA3,CA4,CA5**

The result should be in a structured format for a given `pid` irrespective of the order in which it is stored in Name column as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the names alone to be in order you can use the `ORDER BY` clause

```
select * from table1 order by Name asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(Val ORDER BY Name ASC SEPARATOR  ' ') 
FROM  
    tablename 
WHERE 
     Pid = '123'
GROUP BY 
     Pid;
```

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/156ca/11

Answer (score 0):

try out this...

```
select val from table1 where pid='123' order by Name asc
```

or for all column

```
select * from table1 where pid='123' order by Name asc
```